# How to resize a selected image in slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I have a number of selected images through a bunch of presentations that I need to size to a standard size. I was wondering how do I get my script below running for just the "selected" image(s) on the current slide.

I found a solution where someone got it working for all images on the slide, but I am looking for just those objects that are selected (multiple and single).

I tried altering the code below, but to no success!

```
function rearrangeImages() {
  //Select current page
  var currentPage = 
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
  var slide = currentPage;
  //Get selected images of CurrentPage
  var pageElements = slide.getImages();
  //For each image, change the size and position
  for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    pageElements[i].select(true);
    var image = pageElements[i];
    var imgWidth = image.getWidth();
    var newWidth = 690; 
    var imgHeight = image.getHeight();
    var forhold = imgHeight/imgWidth;
    var newHeight = forhold*newWidth;
    image.setLeft(14).setTop(14).setWidth(newWidth).setHeight(newHeight).setRotation(0);
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
   // ui.alert (imgWidth);
    pageElements[i].select(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to resize a selected image.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

`getSelection()` directly retrieves the selected objects. In this modification, this is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function rearrangeImages() {
  var selectedObjects = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection(); // Modified
  if (selectedObjects.getSelectionType() == SlidesApp.SelectionType.PAGE_ELEMENT) { // Added
    var pageElements = selectedObjects.getPageElementRange().getPageElements(); // Added
    for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
      if (pageElements[i].getPageElementType() == SlidesApp.PageElementType.IMAGE) { // Added
        //For each image, change the size and position
        pageElements[i].select(true);
        var image = pageElements[i];
        var imgWidth = image.getWidth();
        var newWidth = 690; 
        var imgHeight = image.getHeight();
        var forhold = imgHeight/imgWidth;
        var newHeight = forhold*newWidth;
        image.setLeft(14).setTop(14).setWidth(newWidth).setHeight(newHeight).setRotation(0);
        var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
       // ui.alert (imgWidth);
        pageElements[i].select(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- From your title, I thought that you want to resize only images. So this modified script resizes only selected images. If you want to resize the objects except for images, please remove `if (pageElements[i].getPageElementType() == SlidesApp.PageElementType.IMAGE)`.

#### References:

- [Class Selection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection)
- [Selecting items within a presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting)
- [getPageElementRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection#getPageElementRange())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tanaike! This worked and is just what I needed!!! I understand now more about the structure of If statements for this now. Thanks, super helpful!

Comment: @Leah Korganowski Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.